# Google analytics API data to SQL via Python 2.7

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, google-analytics

Out of my depth here.

Have an assignment to download data from web and get it into SQL lite.
have pieced together some different code.

the key code is below.  Suggestions on fixing how to get the data into the SQL table appreciated.

The API code works fine,  It downloads a header row, and rows containing a country name and visitor numbers from that country.  so its the SQL that i'm trying to write thats failing.  No errors, just no data going in.

```
return service.data().ga().get(
     ids='ga:' + profile_id,
     start_date='2016-04-01',
     end_date='today',
     metrics='ga:users',
     dimensions='ga:country').execute()

def print_results(results):
     print()
     print('Profile Name: %s' %results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName'))
     print()
```

## Print header.

```
     output = []
     for header in results.get('columnHeaders'):output.append('%30s' % header.get('name'))
     print(''.join(output))
```

## Print data table.

## start databasing results

```
     if results.get('rows', []):
          for row in results.get('rows'):
          output = []
          for cell in row:output.append('%30s' % cell)
          cur.execute('SELECT max(id) FROM Orign')
          try:
               row = cur.fetchone()
               if row[0] is not None:start = row[0]
          except:
               start = 0
               row = None
               cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Origin (id, Country, Users)
               VALUES ( ?, ?, )''', ( Country, Users))
               conn.commit()
               cur.close()

     print(''.join(output))
     start = 0


     else:
          print('No Rows Found')

 if __name__ == '__main__':
      main(sys.argv)
```